# Retrieve a html table using readHTMLTable

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, html-table, rcurl

I am trying to retrieve in **R** the price from SGX website.

```
myUrl="http://www.sgx.com/wps/portal/sgxweb/home/marketinfo/securities/etfs/!ut/p/c5/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3gjR0cTDwNnA0sDC3cLA0_XsDBfFzcPQ_dQQ6B8JJK8hZG7uYGnoVmgs2GIs7G3qwlJuv1DDYG6Q50CTZzCQg29Pc0I6PbzyM9N1S_IDY0od1RUBADjR8NU/dl3/d3/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/"  

x=readHTMLTable(myUrl,which="priceTableData")  

Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an inherited method for
function ‘readHTMLTable’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
```

Comment: Please see `?readHTMLTable` especially for the `which` argument: "an **integer** vector identifying which tables to return from within the document"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use `readHTMLTable` there because, the table that you are looking for is not in the HTML file retrieved by the url you gave. The table is actually dynamically created by javascript code inside that page.

Typically such javascript codes retrieve data in `json` format by making seperate http query. If you are lucky, you can fetch this `json` data yourself. You can use javascript debugger in your browser (hopefully it's google chrome or firefox) to find out what's the URL for the json data.

Here is quick screenshot of Google chrome's javascript debugger where you can find the link to `json` data. On clicking refresh icon in the webpage, Network tab in the debugger displays all the network requests made by the page.

[image]

You can right click the relevant network request row, and copy the url

It will look like

```
http://www.sgx.com/JsonRead/JsonData?qryId=REtf&timeout=60&%20noCache=1364900004343.639397.7228688071
```

which I think can be simply be reduced to following as `timeout` and `noCache` variables in the URL request seem to be optional intuitively.

```
http://www.sgx.com/JsonRead/JsonData?qryId=REtf
```

The data given by this URL is as follows and is probably what you want.

```
{}&& {identifier:'ID', label:'As at 02-04-2013 5:04 PM',items:[{ID:0,N:'ABF SG BOND ETF',SIP:'@',NC:'A35',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:1.180,C:0.000,VL:7000.000,BV:8000.000,B:'1.175',S:'1.18',SV:49000.000,O:1.180,H:1.180,L:1.180,V:8260.000,SC:'8',PV:1.180,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:1,N:'CIMB APAC Div 100S$D',SIP:'',NC:'QR9',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:1000.000,B:'1.364',S:'1.373',SV:1000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:1.361,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:2,N:'CIMB APAC Div 100US$',SIP:'',NC:'P5P',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:20000.000,B:'1.1',S:'1.109',SV:20000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:1.092,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:3,N:'CIMBASEAN40 100S$D',SIP:'',NC:'QS0',R:'XD',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:100.000,B:'13.74',S:'13.84',SV:100.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:13.930,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:4,N:'CIMBASEAN40 100US$',SIP:'',NC:'M62',R:'XD',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:10.970,C:-0.530,VL:9500.000,BV:2000.000,B:'11.03',S:'11.12',SV:2000.000,O:11.120,H:11.120,L:10.970,V:104862.000,SC:'8',PV:11.500,IOPV:0.000,P:-4.6086953125,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:5,N:'DBXT ASX200 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'LF1',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:2500.000,B:'40.93',S:'41.06',SV:2500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:40.810,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:6,N:'DBXT AUDBonds 5AU$',SIP:'X@',NC:'K6Y',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:184.720,C:2.580,VL:400.000,BV:500.000,B:'183.95',S:'184.75',SV:500.000,O:184.720,H:184.720,L:184.720,V:73888.000,SC:'8',PV:182.140,IOPV:0.000,P:1.41649267578125,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:7,N:'DBXT AUDCS 5AU$',SIP:'X@',NC:'KV5',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:500.000,B:'207.95',S:'208.2',SV:500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:207.620,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:8,N:'DBXT AUDCS 5SG$',SIP:'X@',NC:'KV7',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:250.000,B:'269.25',S:'270.05',SV:250.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:267.400,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:9,N:'DBXT AUDCS 5US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'KV6',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:250.000,B:'217.44',S:'218.14',SV:250.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:215.850,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:10,N:'DBXT China25 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'HD8',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:27.820,C:-0.180,VL:2150.000,BV:2000.000,B:'27.97',S:'28.1',SV:2000.000,O:27.820,H:27.820,L:27.820,V:59813.000,SC:'8',PV:28.000,IOPV:0.000,P:-0.642857177734375,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:11,N:'DBXT CSI300 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'KT4',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:7.800,C:0.000,VL:88360.000,BV:10000.000,B:'7.81',S:'7.83',SV:10000.000,O:7.800,H:7.830,L:7.730,V:686716.000,SC:'8',PV:7.800,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:12,N:'DBXT DBCBLEB 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'L5G',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:2500.000,B:'19.55',S:'19.62',SV:2500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:21.200,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:13,N:'DBXT DBCDJUBS10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'L5F',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:1500.000,B:'31.72',S:'31.84',SV:1500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:31.730,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:14,N:'DBXT DBLCI-OY 5US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'J0S',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:1500.000,B:'37.22',S:'37.36',SV:1500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:37.500,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:15,N:'DBXT E50 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'IH0',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:1500.000,B:'39.93',S:'40.05',SV:1500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:40.290,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:16,N:'DBXT EONIA 5US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'KV8',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:250.000,B:'179.1',S:'179.75',SV:250.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:183.330,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:17,N:'DBXT iBoxxKR 5US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'KT2',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:500.000,B:'140.49',S:'141.69',SV:500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:141.930,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:18,N:'DBXT iBoxxSing5SG$',SIP:'X@',NC:'KV4',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:500.000,B:'129.78',S:'130.28',SV:500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:130.230,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:19,N:'DBXT iBoxxSvEu5US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'KF6',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:300.000,B:'244.53',S:'246.13',SV:300.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:237.390,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:20,N:'DBXT iBoxxUSTr5US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'KF7',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:300.000,B:'207.59',S:'208.59',SV:300.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:206.100,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:21,N:'DBXT MS SING 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'O9A',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:50000.000,B:'1.335',S:'1.339',SV:50000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:1.317,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:22,N:'DBXT MSAsExJp10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'IH1',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:4000.000,B:'32.95',S:'33.1',SV:4000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:33.060,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:23,N:'DBXT MSASPAC 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'O9B',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:16500.000,B:'3.7',S:'3.71',SV:16500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:3.710,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:24,N:'DBXT MSAXJHDY10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'N2F',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:33000.000,B:'1.82',S:'1.828',SV:33000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:1.850,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:25,N:'DBXT MSBANGL 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'O9C',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.804,C:0.004,VL:70170.000,BV:31000.000,B:'0.805',S:'0.812',SV:31000.000,O:0.798,H:0.804,L:0.798,V:56031.000,SC:'8',PV:0.800,IOPV:0.000,P:0.500000048828125,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:26,N:'DBXT MSBrazil10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'J0O',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:7400.000,B:'5.42',S:'5.46',SV:7400.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:5.410,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:27,N:'DBXT MSCHINA 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'LG9',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:11.750,C:0.000,VL:15000.000,BV:5000.000,B:'11.72',S:'11.77',SV:5000.000,O:11.660,H:11.750,L:11.660,V:175700.000,SC:'8',PV:11.750,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:28,N:'DBXT MSEmer 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'J0M',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:16000.000,B:'4.02',S:'4.03',SV:16000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:4.030,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:29,N:'DBXT MSEMAsia10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'J0N',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:100000.000,B:'3.82',S:'3.83',SV:100000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:3.830,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:30,N:'DBXT MSEurope10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'IH3',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:1400.000,B:'49.27',S:'49.5',SV:1400.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:49.200,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:31,N:'DBXT MSINDIA 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'LG8',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:8.620,C:-0.030,VL:6700.000,BV:6700.000,B:'8.72',S:'8.76',SV:6700.000,O:8.620,H:8.620,L:8.620,V:57754.000,SC:'8',PV:8.650,IOPV:0.000,P:-0.3468208251953125,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:32,N:'DBXT MSINDO 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'KJ7',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:16.830,C:-0.220,VL:38000.000,BV:3500.000,B:'16.88',S:'16.97',SV:3500.000,O:16.980,H:17.030,L:16.830,V:644380.000,SC:'8',PV:17.050,IOPV:0.000,P:-1.29032265625,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:33,N:'DBXT MSJAP 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'LF2',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:1500.000,B:'40.64',S:'40.81',SV:1500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:40.900,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:34,N:'DBXT MSKorea 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'IH2',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:58.800,C:-0.040,VL:10.000,BV:850.000,B:'58.11',S:'58.39',SV:850.000,O:58.800,H:58.800,L:58.800,V:588.000,SC:'8',PV:58.840,IOPV:0.000,P:-0.06798096923828124,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:35,N:'DBXT MSMSIA 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'LG6',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:3900.000,B:'14.22',S:'14.28',SV:3900.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:14.100,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:36,N:'DBXT MSPacXJp10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'J0Q',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:16000.000,B:'5.19',S:'5.22',SV:16000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:5.010,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:37,N:'DBXT MSPAKIS 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'O9D',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:24000.000,B:'1.367',S:'1.373',SV:24000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:1.355,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:38,N:'DBXT MSPHILS 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'N2E',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:2.130,C:-0.025,VL:7000.000,BV:40000.000,B:'2.122',S:'2.13',SV:40000.000,O:2.130,H:2.130,L:2.130,V:14910.000,SC:'8',PV:2.155,IOPV:0.000,P:-1.16009287109375,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:39,N:'DBXT MSRussia10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'J0R',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:18000.000,B:'2.96',S:'2.97',SV:18000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:2.980,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:40,N:'DBXT MSTaiwan10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'HD7',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:18.370,C:-0.120,VL:300.000,BV:2900.000,B:'18.38',S:'18.46',SV:2900.000,O:18.370,H:18.370,L:18.370,V:5511.000,SC:'8',PV:18.490,IOPV:0.000,P:-0.648999462890625,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:41,N:'DBXT MSTHAI 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'LG7',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:22.500,C:-0.100,VL:5200.000,BV:2600.000,B:'22.6',S:'22.71',SV:2600.000,O:22.440,H:22.500,L:22.440,V:116844.000,SC:'8',PV:22.600,IOPV:0.000,P:-0.442477880859375,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:42,N:'DBXT MSUSA 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'KF8',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:1650.000,B:'38.47',S:'38.61',SV:1650.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:36.780,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:43,N:'DBXT MSWorld 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'J0P',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:16000.000,B:'3.65',S:'3.67',SV:16000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:3.680,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:44,N:'DBXT Nifty 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'HE0',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:106.100,C:-0.340,VL:470.000,BV:470.000,B:'107.29',S:'107.78',SV:470.000,O:106.100,H:106.100,L:106.100,V:49867.000,SC:'8',PV:106.440,IOPV:0.000,P:-0.31942880859375,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:45,N:'DBXT S&P500 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'K6K',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:25.590,C:0.080,VL:50.000,BV:3000.000,B:'25.54',S:'25.65',SV:3000.000,O:25.590,H:25.590,L:25.590,V:1279.000,SC:'8',PV:25.510,IOPV:0.000,P:0.3136025146484375,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:46,N:'DBXT S&PShort10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'HD6',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:1500.000,B:'31.5',S:'31.58',SV:1500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:31.620,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:47,N:'DBXT SORA 5SG$',SIP:'X@',NC:'KJ6',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:500.000,B:'107.36',S:'107.66',SV:500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:107.380,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:48,N:'DBXT STGLDv 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'KT3',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:1900.000,B:'30.11',S:'30.25',SV:1900.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:29.900,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:49,N:'DBXT USDCS 5US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'IH4',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:500.000,B:'170.72',S:'170.91',SV:500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:170.640,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:50,N:'DBXT USDIGInfl5US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'KF5',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:300.000,B:'287.36',S:'289.36',SV:300.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:286.670,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:51,N:'DBXT Vietnam 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'HD9',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:26.200,C:0.240,VL:900.000,BV:2000.000,B:'26.23',S:'26.3',SV:2000.000,O:26.200,H:26.200,L:26.200,V:23580.000,SC:'8',PV:25.960,IOPV:0.000,P:0.92449921875,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:52,N:'GLD 10US$',SIP:'@',NC:'O87',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:154.840,C:0.400,VL:13050.000,BV:10.000,B:'154.68',S:'154.84',SV:100.000,O:155.080,H:155.100,L:154.700,V:2022693.000,SC:'8',PV:154.440,IOPV:154.549,P:0.259000244140625,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:53,N:'IS ASIA BND 100S$D',SIP:'@',NC:'QL2',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:500.000,B:'13.4',S:'13.49',SV:500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:13.380,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:54,N:'IS ASIA BND 100US$',SIP:'@',NC:'N6M',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:10.850,C:0.000,VL:61000.000,BV:500.000,B:'10.76',S:'10.85',SV:5100.000,O:10.850,H:10.850,L:10.850,V:658805.000,SC:'8',PV:10.850,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:55,N:'IS ASIA HYG100S$D',SIP:'@',NC:'QL3',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:700.000,B:'13.8',S:'13.86',SV:500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:13.970,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:56,N:'IS ASIA HYG100US$',SIP:'@',NC:'O9P',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:11.120,C:-0.060,VL:49800.000,BV:1100.000,B:'11.1',S:'11.19',SV:100.000,O:11.120,H:11.120,L:11.120,V:556241.000,SC:'8',PV:11.180,IOPV:0.000,P:-0.536672607421875,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:57,N:'IS DJ USTECH 10US$',SIP:'@',NC:'I21',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:800.000,B:'72.39',S:'73.09',SV:800.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:72.860,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:58,N:'IS LC 1-3Y 100S$D',SIP:'@',NC:'QL0',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:12.940,C:-0.040,VL:100.000,BV:100.000,B:'12.92',S:'12.95',SV:100.000,O:12.940,H:12.940,L:12.940,V:1294.000,SC:'8',PV:12.980,IOPV:0.000,P:-0.30816640625,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:59,N:'IS LC 1-3Y 100US$',SIP:'@',NC:'O9Q',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:100.000,B:'10.4',S:'10.49',SV:100.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:10.400,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:60,N:'IS LC BND 100S$D',SIP:'@',NC:'QL1',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:500.000,B:'13.18',S:'13.27',SV:500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:12.990,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:61,N:'IS LC BND 100US$',SIP:'@',NC:'N6L',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:500.000,B:'10.62',S:'10.71',SV:500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:10.670,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:62,N:'IS MS INDIA 100S$D',SIP:'@',NC:'QK9',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:500.000,B:'7.61',S:'7.7',SV:500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:7.640,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:63,N:'IS MS INDIA 100US$',SIP:'@',NC:'I98',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:6.210,C:0.060,VL:55400.000,BV:145000.000,B:'6.19',S:'6.23',SV:70000.000,O:6.060,H:6.210,L:6.060,V:341371.000,SC:'8',PV:6.150,IOPV:6.229,P:0.975609765625,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:64,N:'IS MSCI SIN 100US$',SIP:'@',NC:'I19',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:4000.000,B:'13.93',S:'13.98',SV:19000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:13.710,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:65,N:'IS S&P500 10US$',SIP:'@',NC:'I17',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:156.920,C:-0.070,VL:1000.000,BV:500.000,B:'156.95',S:'157.67',SV:350.000,O:156.920,H:156.920,L:156.920,V:156920.000,SC:'8',PV:156.990,IOPV:0.000,P:-0.04458882751464844,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:66,N:'Lyxor Asia 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'P60',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:30000.000,B:'4.78',S:'4.83',SV:30000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:4.790,IOPV:4.840,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:67,N:'Lyxor AsiaCS 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'NF6',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:1000.000,B:'56.24',S:'56.9',SV:1000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:56.090,IOPV:56.580,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:68,N:'Lyxor AsiaFN 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'NF5',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:2000.000,B:'31.61',S:'31.96',SV:2000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:26.310,IOPV:31.810,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:69,N:'Lyxor AsiaIF 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'NF3',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:2000.000,B:'33.27',S:'33.62',SV:2000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:32.850,IOPV:33.500,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:70,N:'Lyxor AsiaIT 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'NF4',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:2000.000,B:'30.',S:'30.35',SV:2000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:25.290,IOPV:30.180,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:71,N:'Lyxor AsiaMT 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'NF7',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:1000.000,B:'48.58',S:'49.16',SV:1000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:49.070,IOPV:48.830,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:72,N:'Lyxor AsiaRE 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'MT7',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:3000.000,B:'10.59',S:'10.7',SV:3000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:10.720,IOPV:10.650,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:73,N:'Lyxor ChinaH 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'P58',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:20000.000,B:'13.93',S:'14.26',SV:20000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:14.440,IOPV:14.080,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:74,N:'Lyxor Cmdty 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'A0W',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:31000.000,B:'2.74',S:'2.8',SV:30000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:2.740,IOPV:2.740,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:75,N:'Lyxor CRBxEny10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'G1O',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:26600.000,B:'2.48',S:'2.54',SV:25000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:2.510,IOPV:2.510,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:76,N:'Lyxor EastEur10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'H1M',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:10000.000,B:'4.4',S:'4.61',SV:10000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:4.850,IOPV:4.500,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:77,N:'Lyxor EM Mkt 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'H1N',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:10000.000,B:'10.28',S:'10.47',SV:10000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:10.210,IOPV:10.370,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:78,N:'Lyxor Europe 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'JC5',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:5000.000,B:'13.06',S:'13.21',SV:5000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:13.190,IOPV:13.180,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:79,N:'Lyxor HSI 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'A9B',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:30000.000,B:'2.82',S:'2.85',SV:1000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:2.900,IOPV:2.840,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:80,N:'Lyxor Indonesia10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'P2Q',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:500.000,B:'106.55',S:'108.15',SV:500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:102.870,IOPV:107.080,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:81,N:'Lyxor Japan 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'CW4',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:1.069,C:0.001,VL:2500.000,BV:57500.000,B:'1.066',S:'1.076',SV:60000.000,O:1.069,H:1.069,L:1.069,V:2672.000,SC:'8',PV:1.068,IOPV:1.060,P:0.09363296508789062,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:82,N:'Lyxor Korea 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'AO9',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:15000.000,B:'5.14',S:'5.2',SV:15000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:5.200,IOPV:5.170,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:83,N:'Lyxor LATAM 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'H1O',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:10000.000,B:'7.61',S:'7.73',SV:10000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:7.410,IOPV:7.680,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:84,N:'Lyxor MAL 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'G1M',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:10000.000,B:'9.8',S:'9.94',SV:10000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:9.420,IOPV:9.860,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:85,N:'Lyxor MSIndia10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'G1N',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:26000.000,B:'13.71',S:'13.84',SV:20000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:13.590,IOPV:13.870,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:86,N:'Lyxor Nasdaq 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'H1Q',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:11.110,C:-0.070,VL:1900.000,BV:8100.000,B:'11.15',S:'11.25',SV:10000.000,O:11.110,H:11.110,L:11.110,V:21109.000,SC:'8',PV:11.180,IOPV:11.170,P:-0.62611806640625,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:87,N:'Lyxor Russia 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'JC7',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:7500.000,B:'3.73',S:'3.81',SV:7500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:3.870,IOPV:3.940,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:88,N:'Lyxor Taiwan 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'A9A',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.970,C:0.000,VL:3000.000,BV:27000.000,B:'0.975',S:'0.986',SV:30000.000,O:0.970,H:0.970,L:0.970,V:2910.000,SC:'8',PV:0.970,IOPV:0.980,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:89,N:'Lyxor ThaiSET 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'P2P',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:500.000,B:'143.6',S:'145.24',SV:500.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:104.920,IOPV:145.210,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:90,N:'Lyxor USDJIA 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'JC6',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:5000.000,B:'14.73',S:'14.87',SV:5000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:14.620,IOPV:14.790,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:91,N:'Lyxor World 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'H1P',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:50000.000,B:'1.431',S:'1.454',SV:50000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:1.418,IOPV:1.450,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:92,N:'LYXOR Asia EX 10US$',SIP:'X@',NC:'G1K',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:20000.000,B:'4.47',S:'4.52',SV:20000.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:4.440,IOPV:4.480,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:93,N:'Nikko AM STI ETF100',SIP:'@',NC:'G3B',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:3.370,C:0.000,VL:2100.000,BV:31000.000,B:'3.36',S:'3.38',SV:4500.000,O:3.360,H:3.370,L:3.360,V:7057.000,SC:'8',PV:3.370,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:94,N:'SPDR DJIA 10US$',SIP:'@',NC:'D07',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:0.000,B:'',S:'',SV:0.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:108.600,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:95,N:'SPDR S&P500 10US$',SIP:'@',NC:'S27',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:0.000,C:0.000,VL:0.000,BV:10.000,B:'155.6',S:'',SV:0.000,O:0.000,H:0.000,L:0.000,V:0.000,SC:'8',PV:155.300,IOPV:0.000,P:0.0,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:96,N:'STI ETF',SIP:'@',NC:'ES3',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:3.350,C:0.010,VL:35000.000,BV:1000.000,B:'3.34',S:'3.35',SV:74000.000,O:3.330,H:3.350,L:3.320,V:116640.000,SC:'8',PV:3.340,IOPV:3.350,P:0.299401220703125,P_:'',V_:''},{ID:97,N:'UETF SSE50China100',SIP:'X@',NC:'JK8',R:'NONE',I:'NONE',M:'-',LT:1.730,C:-0.010,VL:88800.000,BV:6000.000,B:'1.73',S:'1.76',SV:44500.000,O:1.740,H:1.740,L:1.730,V:153970.000,SC:'8',PV:1.740,IOPV:0.000,P:-0.574712646484375,P_:'',V_:''}]}
```

Now all you need to do is parse this json data and get your data.

Comment: Thank you that is a great answer. I have followed your tutorial and I am now trying to parse the json file. I am doing:

library("rjson");json_data = fromJSON(file='http://www.sgx.com/JsonRead/JsonData?qryId=REtf') Is there anything I do wrong? The list inside the json object is empty

Comment: @RockScience I suggest you create seperate question for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't going to automate this (i.e. one-and-done), the solution that works every time is to go to the Developer Tools in your favorite browser and copy the contents of the HTML node into a new file with an HTML extension.  This works because the DOM represented in the Developer Tools is the *rendered* DOM, meaning that all data transfer scripts have already been run on it.

This will give you an HTML file with the table fully rendered.  You can load this normally, e.g. `my.data <- readHTMLTable("C:/Users/username/Desktop/webpage.htm", header = TRUE, which = 1)`.

I recently had to do this with some CDC data that didn't have an exposed API to work with.  If you have the option of using an API, please do it because it's much cleaner and easier.